# php-How to calcluate number of the dot (. ) in the paragraph?

Tags: php

I want to count the number of dot (.)in the paragraph.how to do this.
I know the str_word_count() and strlen().but how to use in this counting the dot in the paragraph.

```
<?php

$str = "Hello fri3nd, you're
       looking          good today!";

print_r(str_word_count($str, 1));
print_r(str_word_count($str, 2));
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, 'àáãç3'));

echo str_word_count($str);

?>
```

Comment: Why do you put standard example from PHP documentation of using of str_word_count() here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/function.substr-count.php)

```
echo substr_count($str, '.');
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/166565

Answer (score 1):

```
echo substr_count('test . abc. asdasdsasadsadsadas...', '.');   // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

there is inbuilt function in PHP to do that as mentioned by others..A simple `Brute force approach` is here

```
<?php

 $str = "Hello ....fri3nd, you're
   looking          good today!";
 $cnt =  0;

 for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($str);$i++) {

     if ($str[$i] == '.') {
        $cnt++;
     }
 }

 echo $cnt;

?>
```

Comment: brute force approach! ha! haha. Can also use str_split() then foreach.